# If not match - how to use function, for numbers which cannot be repeated

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Column A I have around 6000 cells with different records, depending on many conditions I need to add one number from Column C to Column B. In Column C I have 3000 cell with numbers/texts (A:G304,B:Z503,C:B406,D:Z3098 ect.). My formula for all arguments is working fine.I need to add one more condition and I don't know how: I need to make sure number I want tu use in Column B is not matchnig to any other numbers in Column B (numbers can not be repeated). Is anybody has a idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Data Validation** feature to avoid duplicate values.

You can find the **Data Validation** under **DATA** tab.

1. Select the range in the *column B*
2. Select *Custom* for **Allow**
3. In **Formula** section enter the validation formula. For example;

   ```
   =COUNTIF($B$1:$B$1000,B1)<2
   ```
4. Of course you can update the formula as your data fits. However be sure that first argument should be absolute reference (($) while second is relative (B1).

This link has detailed information: [How to create Excel data validation for unique values](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/excel-data-validation/)